# Trying to return both the value and innerText of Angular select option

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-select, select-options

Here is an example of my payload

```
    0: { category: “BRAINS”,         description: "test 1234124”,         userNumber: “789456123”,         accountType: “WOW”,         balance: {amount: 12.34, currency: “USD”},         uniqueId: “47823748923hfhjfew32847hw43879=” },         

1: { category: “DIET”,         description: "test 1234124”, userNumber: “123456789”,         accountType: “WOW”,         balance: {amount: 43.21, currency: “GBP”},         uniqueId: “47823748923hfhjfew32847hw43879=” },

    2: { category: “MEAT”,         description: "test 1234124”,         userNumber: “951234679”,         accountType: “WOW”,         balance: {amount: 26.56, currency: “EUR”},         uniqueId: “47823748923hfhjfew32847hw43879=” },
```

I want to return both the value and the inner text of the select option, so both the value ‘uniqueId’ and the inner text ‘userNumber’

My HTML

```
<select #category="ngModel" name=“user” id=“user” class="form-control" #test [(ngModel)]="model.user” (change)="doSomething(test.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let user of users” [value]=“user.uniqueId”>
       {{user.userNumber}}
    </option>
</select>
```

My .ts file

```
doSomething(value) {
      console.log(value); 
      // returns the value 47823748923hfhjfew32847hw43879=
}

    onAddValue() {
          console.log('yoyoyoy', this.model); 
         // returns {value: undefined, uniqueId: "47823748923hfhjfew32847hw43879="}
          console.log('accountNumber', this.model.user); //returns 47823748923hfhjfew32847hw43879=
}
```

Trying to return both the value and innerText of Angular select option

Basically this is what I want to be able to do

http://jsfiddle.net/5bzkfwrt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change this:

```
 (change)="doSomething($event,test.value)"
```

in .ts

```
doSomething(event,value) {
      console.log(value); 

}
```

Comment: Hi I got it to work like this
 console.log(event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].text); 
console.log(value);